# Syntax for gRPC-server stream

Tags: go, syntax, protocol-buffers, grpc

In the GetList function the client sends a message and the StreamReply returns  RowValue and boolean value from a loop one by one. How can I implement it with gRPC stream?

test.proto

```
service GetList {
  rpc Listdata (StreamRequest) returns (stream StreamReply){}
}

message StreamRequest{
  string StreamName= 1;
  bool boolean= 3;
}

message StreamReply{
  string RowValue=1;
  bool boolean = 2;
}
```

The problem lies in my go function. I don't understand how to simply stream values using stream.Send()

server.go

```
func (s *server) GetList(in *pb.StreamRequest, stream pb.GetList_ListdataServer) error {
        strings:= "random strings"
        count := 5
        for i := 0; i < count; i++ {
            if err := stream.Send(strings, true); err != nil {
                return err
            }
        }

    return nil
}
```

Comment: You need to use the response message type: `stream.Send(&pb.StreamReply{RowValue:strings,Boolean:true})`

Comment: This worked nicely